# SQL interpolating missing values for a specific date range - with some conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, time-series, interpolation

There are some similar questions on the site, but I believe mine warrants a new post because there are specific conditions that need to be incorporated.

I have a table with monthly intervals, structured like this:

```
+----+--------+--------------+--------------+
| ID | amount | interval_beg | interval_end |
+----+--------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 |     10 | 12/17/2017   | 1/17/2018    |
|  1 |     10 | 1/18/2018    | 2/18/2018    |
|  1 |     10 | 2/19/2018    | 3/19/2018    |
|  1 |     10 | 3/20/2018    | 4/20/2018    |
|  1 |     10 | 4/21/2018    | 5/21/2018    |
+----+--------+--------------+--------------+
```

I've found that sometimes there is a month of data missing around the end/beginning of the year where I know it should exist, like this:

```
+----+--------+--------------+--------------+
| ID | amount | interval_beg | interval_end |
+----+--------+--------------+--------------+
|  2 |     10 | 10/14/2018   | 11/14/2018   |
|  2 |     10 | 11/15/2018   | 12/15/2018   |
|  2 |     10 | 1/17/2019    | 2/17/2019    |
|  2 |     10 | 2/18/2019    | 3/18/2019    |
|  2 |     10 | 3/19/2019    | 4/19/2019    |
+----+--------+--------------+--------------+
```

What I need is a statement that will:

1. Identify where this year-end period is missing (but not find missing
   months that *aren't* at the beginning/end of the year).
2. Create this interval by using the length of an existing interval for
   that ID (maybe using the mean interval length for the ID to do it?). I could create the interval from the "gap" between the previous and next interval, except that won't work if I'm missing an interval at the beginning or end of the ID's record (i.e. if the record starts at say 1/16/2015, I need the amount for 12/15/2014-1/15/2015
3. Interpolate an 'amount' for this interval using the mean daily
   'amount' from the closest existing interval.

The end result for the sample above should look like:

```
+----+--------+--------------+--------------+
| ID | amount | interval_beg | interval_end |
+----+--------+--------------+--------------+
|  2 |     10 | 10/14/2018   | 11/14/2018   |
|  2 |     10 | 11/15/2018   | 12/15/2018   |
|  2 |     10 | 12/16/2018   | 1/16/2018    |
|  2 |     10 | 1/17/2019    | 2/17/2019    |
|  2 |     10 | 2/18/2019    | 3/18/2019    |
+----+--------+--------------+--------------+
```

A 'nice to have' would be a flag indicating that this value is interpolated.

Is there a way to do this efficiently in SQL? I have written a solution in SAS, but have a need to move it to SQL, and my SAS solution is very inefficient (optimization isn't a goal, so any statement that does what I need is fantastic).

EDIT: I've made an SQLFiddle with my example table here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8b16d

Comment: Please tag a DBMS (Oracle, MySQL, etc). Any answers will need to be specific to your particular dialect of SQL.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) - but consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Thanks! I may be wording things incorrectly because I'm not very familiar with SQL (thus I'm asking for a solution for what should be a pretty simple procedure). I don't need to merely query from the database, I want to write to the table, so that this information is stored in the DB.  I'd like to have a flag so that I can easily go back and determine which values are interpolated and which are "raw".

Comment: Your fiddle is MySQL but the question tagged SQL server. Which one is it? And what is the expected output for the sample data in the fiddle?

Comment: Thanks for commenting @Nick! It should be SQL Server - I accidentally used MySQL to set up the fiddle and wasn't able to access the site to correct it, I've updated the link now. I'm not sure I understand your second question... The fiddle just sets up a schema with the example data I'm using to test the problem. The output I want to get is detailed in my post above.

Comment: @AlJones1816 your fiddle has much more data in it than your question. I just wanted to be clear which intervals you expect the query to generate for the data in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sequence of CTEs to build up the data for the missing periods. In this query, the first CTE (`EOYS`) generates all the end-of-year dates (`YYYY-12-31`) relevant to the table; the second (`INTERVALS`) the average interval length for each `ID` and the third (`MISSING`) attempts to find start (from `t2`) and end (from `t3`) dates of adjoining intervals for any missing (indicated by `t1.ID IS NULL`) end-of-year interval. The output of this CTE is then used in an `INSERT ... SELECT` query to add missing interval records to the table, generating missing dates by adding/subtracting the interval length to the end/start date of the adjacent interval as necessary.

First though we add the `interp` column to indicate if a row was interpolated:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD interp TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

This sets `interp` to `0` for all existing rows. Then we can do the `INSERT`, setting `interp` for all those rows to `1`:

```
WITH EOYS AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, interval_beg), 12, 31) AS eoy
  FROM Table1
),
INTERVALS AS (
  SELECT ID, AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, interval_beg, interval_end)) AS interval_len
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY ID
),
MISSING AS (
  SELECT e.eoy, 
         ids.ID, 
         i.interval_len, 
         COALESCE(t2.amount, t3.amount) AS amount, 
         DATEADD(DAY,  1, t2.interval_end) AS interval_beg, 
         DATEADD(DAY, -1, t3.interval_beg) AS interval_end
  FROM EOYS e
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Table1) ids
  JOIN INTERVALS i ON i.ID = ids.ID
  LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON ids.ID = t1.ID
                     AND e.eoy BETWEEN t1.interval_beg AND t1.interval_end
  LEFT JOIN Table1 t2 ON ids.ID = t2.ID
                     AND DATEADD(MONTH, -1, e.eoy) BETWEEN t2.interval_beg AND t2.interval_end
  LEFT JOIN Table1 t3 ON ids.ID = t3.ID
                     AND DATEADD(MONTH,  1, e.eoy) BETWEEN t3.interval_beg AND t3.interval_end
  WHERE t1.ID IS NULL
)
INSERT INTO Table1 (ID, amount, interval_beg, interval_end, interp)
SELECT ID,
       amount,
       COALESCE(interval_beg, DATEADD(DAY, -interval_len, interval_end)) AS interval_beg,
       COALESCE(interval_end, DATEADD(DAY,  interval_len, interval_beg)) AS interval_end,
       1 AS interp
FROM MISSING
```

This adds the following rows to the table:

```
ID  amount  interval_beg    interval_end    interp
2   10      2017-12-05      2018-01-04      1
2   10      2018-12-16      2019-01-16      1
2   10      2019-12-28      2020-01-27      1
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2fb79/1)

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you so much! You description as very clear and I was able to follow and learn from it. And thanks for being patient as I'm still a newbie and learning proper etiquette.